# Spring error using EL in property placeholder configurer

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am trying to get a property file value loaded from the class path to resolve in a property placeholder configurers locations property, the idea being that I can then load external property files based on the values loaded from the class path file.... an example might make this easier to understand...

1) load from the classpath some properties

```
<bean id="globalProperties" class="common.config.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="key" value="globalProperties" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>              
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>                 
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

2) Now want to use a property loaded above in the next placeholder configurer:

```
<bean id="appProperties" class="common.config.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="key" value="appProperties" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>              
            <value>file:#{globalProperties['app.config']}/app.config.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/app.config.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.dir}/app.config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If I try loading it just using ${} syntax then that is what is used to load the file, which obviously never gets loaded, eg `${app.config}/app.config.properties` (the class cannot be found because the variable was not converted). The system variables `${user.home}` do get converted properly so how do I use a property I have loaded as a value in another property placeholder configurer? Is this possible?

Trying to use the code in my example file:

`#{globalProperties['app.config']}/app.config.properties`

gives a spring error:

```
    Error creating bean with name 'appProperties' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/properties.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1027E:(pos 16): Indexing into type 'common.config.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer' is not supported
```

Comment: Propertyplaceholders aren't loaded and applied in order, they are all loaded at once. You can only use variables which are available from the environment not those loaded from property files.

Comment: Ok thanks, that clears that up then!

Comment: @berimbolo Did you find a solution at the end? Is it somehow possible to use properties of another placeholder in a second placeholder? I tried it also with PropertyOverrideConfigurer without luck.

Comment: Hi @superbly I did but it wasnt really the solution you would be looking for Im afraid, after the response from M. Deinum I made an agreement with the hosting team to always load from ${user.home} which on linux production servers is always /home/tomcat and on my local machine I created a C:\\home\tomcat which still resolves as /home/tomcat locally. I dont think this will help you though, sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But yes it's not the solution I'm seeking.